# MongoRegex decimal number problems

Tags: regex, mongodb, decimal

I need search prices which contains number 2 in start and after . 00-99, but it find prices like 12.00, 25.99, 2.00, 2.28 not only 2.00, 2.28.
Is any idea how fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the regex to do this is simply:

```
/\A2\.[0-9]{2}\Z/
```